# Null vectors that aren't the zero vector in general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, fluid-dynamics, metric-tensor, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, linear-algebra

So I was trying to understand the null energy condition of $T_{μν}k^μk^ν≥0$ Where $k$ is an "arbitrary future-directed null vector" and couldn't really wrap my head around how the $k$ is used in this context.

An example I found [here](http://universeinproblems.com/index.php/Energy_conditions_and_the_Raychaudhuri_equation#Problem_1:_energy_conditions_for_perfect_fluid) where they are using this condition to set conditions on a perfect fluid was using the vector $k^μ=(1,1,0,0)$ and I didn't understand how it is a null vector in this scenario. I partially understand that the metric should be necessary in some way to say that the norm of the null vector becomes zero, but I still can't quite understand it.

Any help would be appreciated. Also, I'm familiar with but don't have a deep understanding of linear algebra/abstract math so simple explanations would be great!

Comment: [Special relativity's enough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space#Scalar_product).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Null doesn't mean zero in this context (unlike other places where "null" and "zero" are synonymous).

A tangent vector $v$ is said to be **null with respect to the metric tensor $g$** if $g(v,v)=0$. Remember that a metric tensor is an object $g$ which eats two vectors and spits out a number. In terms of components, the condition is that $g_{ab}v^av^b=0$, or written out in full glory, $\sum_{a,b=0}^3g_{ab}v^av^b=0$.

In your case, you're being told to consider the standard Lorentzian metric whose components are
\begin{align}
[g_{ab}]&=
\begin{pmatrix}
-1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
(or perhaps there's an overall minus sign; I didn't really check). You're also told to consider the vector $k$ whose components are $k^0=1,k^1=1,k^2=k^3=0$. The claim is that this vecotr $k$ is indeed null with respect to $g$. Why? A very trivial calculation:
\begin{align}
g(k,k)&=\sum_{a,b=0}^3g_{ab}k^ak^b=g_{00}k^0k^0+g_{11}k^1k^1=(-1)(1)(1)+(1)(1)(1)=0.
\end{align}
(the second equality is because all other terms of the summation are zero).